# How to find the second derivative of this function: $x^2 |x|$ at $x = 0$

Tags: calculus

newbie in Calculus here.

I was going to plug it into the definition of derivative function, the exact way my professor showed us to do it, except when he plugged it in, he used the $\sqrt{x}$ as $f(x)$.

I get the rest of what he did after that, but I'm left wondering why he used $\sqrt{x}$ as the function.

I don't get what I'm missing, maybe someone here knows?

Comment: Perhaps your professor was using the fact that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^6}=x^2\left|x\right|$. Is that what he used?

Comment: Here's what the full answer the professor gave me: http://imgur.com/a/IGEKL

Answer (score 1):

Recall $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}.$$  Let $a = 0$ and $f(x) = x^2|x|$. Then $f(a) = 0$ and we have $$f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2|x|}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} x|x| = 0.$$  Now suppose we want the general function $f'(a)$.  Then consider two cases (the third, $a = 0$, was already discussed above).  If $a > 0$, then in a sufficiently small neighborhood of $a$, we have $x > 0$; that is, there exists $0 < x < a$ for any $a > 0$.  Then in this neighborhood, $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^2|x| - a^2|a|}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^3-a^3}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} x^2 + ax + a^2 = 3a^2.$$  Conversely, if $a < 0$, then a similar argument applies:  $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{-x^3 - (-a^3)}{x-a} = -3a^2.$$  We can then put these back together by noting that $$f'(a) = \begin{cases} 3a^2, & a > 0, \\ 0, & a = 0, \\ -3a^2, & a < 0 \end{cases}$$ is equivalent to $$f'(a) = 3a|a|.$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with that first function you gave me, but then maybe I am. Is it an alternate version of (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h ? What about the second derivative, or maybe you gave me that and I missed it?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is show that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} x^3 = \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(-x^3)$ at $x = 0$.

This way you don't have to deal with the absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by mentioning square roots that $$(x^2|x|)'=\left(\sqrt{x^6}\right)'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^6}}\cdot (x^6)'=\frac{3x^5}{|x^3|}=3x|x|?$$ Anyway, this seems to work.

Comment: I added a comment to my original post, showing the approach the professor used, maybe that helps clear this up...